# Visual Basic Script as Windows Scheduled Task

Tags: python, windows, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I am currently trying to create a .bat script for creating a Scheduled Task for both Windows XP and 7. This is a script that will run a Python script with a hidden command line window. Here is the code for the .vbs script:

```
dim fso
dim curDir
dim WinScriptHost
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
set fso = nothing
WScript.echo curDir

Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run ".\Python27\python.exe .\Modules\monitor.py"
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

Here is the .bat script that invokes the .vbs script:

```
schtasks /Create /SC ONLOGON /TN Monitor /TR "%~dp0schedule.vbs"
@ECHO OFF
PAUSE
```

This script does create a Scheduled Task, but when I try to run it, nothing shows up. I can verify that the .vbs script works if you manually run it. Here is the folder heiarchy of my program:

```
\Project
    schedule.vbs
    create_schedule.bat

    \modules
      monitor.py
```

Comment: Did you tried to put the /TR parameter with a full-qualified name? e.g. "C:\local\of\vbs\file\schedule.vbs"

Comment: So I ended up specifying the full path in TR and there was a big issue. Because my account name contains two words, the part up to my first name is the path and the part with my last name til the end is the input parameter.

Program/Script: C:\Users\Some
Arguments: User\Project\.....

I can't seem to fix this issue.

Comment: Put double quotes around paths with embedded space characters.